# Returning a 'type object is not subscriptable' error when importing a class from another .py file?

Tags: python, class, import

Program doesn't make it past the import statement:

```
from platelayout import PlateLayout
```

have tried combing both the running file and the separate file containing the class, but no indication as to what the problem is.

```
/Users/path to directory/callhits.ipynb Cell 1 line 1
     10 from scipy import stats
     12 from hitcaller import HitCaller
---> 13 from platelayout import PlateLayout
     17 rundate   = "230718"
     19 hitsdir   = "hits"

File ~/path to platelayout.py

     10 """
     12 from typing import Tuple
---> 15 class PlateLayout:
     17     @staticmethod
     18     def _getControlWells(plate : str) -> \
     19         Tuple[
     20             list[str],
     21             list[str],
     22             dict[str,list[str]]]:
     24         if (plate.startswith("plate1")   or \
...
     33            (('-'    not in plate) and \
     34             ("rep" not in plate)):
     36             print(plate, "block pos layout")
```

Comment: If you get an error importing third-party libraries, it usually means you have incompatible versions of something.

Comment: Is `platelayout` something you wrote or a third-party library you installed? Please show the full traceback of the error.

Comment: Random guess: Try to add `from __future__ import annotations` near the beginning of the files.

Comment: @Barmar, platelayout is something I wrote.

Comment: Show us the full code for platelayout.py.

Comment: Then it seems like a bug there. The error you're getting implies that you have a variable that's supposed to hold a dictionary or list, but it contains a type. Maybe you forgot `()` somewhere when creating an instance of something.

Comment: This is why we need a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common error related to the typing system. The reason is that the library you're using, subscripted the builtin types in order to give them type hints.

For example in your code you had:

```py
...
     20             list[str],
...
```

Builtin types [had become generic since Python 3.9](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/). This means that if you run your script with the version below 3.9 it fails with that exact same error.  `dict`, `list`, ... didn't support subscription before that.

So make sure your interpreter version is 3.9 and above.

---

I would definitely suggest to upgrade your Python version since that library probably uses other new syntaxes/features as well and you'll face other issues too, but just to fix that specific issue regarding the type hints, you can add this line at the top most line in your main file before other imports:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
```

It basically considers the type hints as strings and post-pones the evaluation.

Comment: bingo, thanks for the help

Comment: @ChrisFazekas Happy to help, Please consider upvoting the answer as well if that helped you